# Conditional variance follow derivation

Tags: probability

Let $Y_{t-1}$ be the vector of observations $\left(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{t-1}\right)^{\prime}$ for $t=2,3, \ldots$ and assume that the conditional distribution of $\alpha_{t}$ given $Y_{t-1}$ is $\mathrm{N}\left(a_{t}, P_{t}\right)$ where $a_{t}$ and $P_{t}$ are known. Assume also that the conditional distribution of $\alpha_{t}$ given $Y_{t}$ is $\mathrm{N}\left(a_{t \mid t}, P_{t \mid t}\right)$. The distribution of $\alpha_{t+1}$ given $Y_{t}$ is $\mathrm{N}\left(a_{t+1}, P_{t+1}\right)$. Our object is to calculate $a_{t \mid t}, P_{t \mid t}, a_{t+1}$ and $P_{t+1}$ when $y_{t}$ is brought in. We refer to $a_{t \mid t}$ as the filtered estimator of the state $\alpha_{t}$ and $a_{t+1}$ as the one-step ahead predictor of $\alpha_{t+1}$. Their respective associated variances are $P_{t \mid t}$ and $P_{t+1}$.

An important part is played by the one-step ahead prediction error $v_{t}$ of $y_{t}$. Then $v_{t}=y_{t}-a_{t}$ for $t=1, \ldots, n$, and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{E}\left(v_{t} \mid Y_{t-1}\right) &=\mathrm{E}\left(\alpha_{t}+\varepsilon_{t}-a_{t} \mid Y_{t-1}\right)=a_{t}-a_{t}=0 \\
\operatorname{Var}\left(v_{t} \mid Y_{t-1}\right) &=\operatorname{Var}\left(\alpha_{t}+\varepsilon_{t}-a_{t} \mid Y_{t-1}\right)=P_{t}+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2} \\
\mathrm{E}\left(v_{t} \mid \alpha_{t}, Y_{t-1}\right) &=\mathrm{E}\left(\alpha_{t}+\varepsilon_{t}-a_{t} \mid \alpha_{t}, Y_{t-1}\right)=\alpha_{t}-a_{t} \\
\operatorname{Var}\left(v_{t} \mid \alpha_{t}, Y_{t-1}\right) &=\operatorname{Var}\left(\alpha_{t}+\varepsilon_{t}-a_{t} \mid \alpha_{t}, Y_{t-1}\right)=\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Please take me through the steps that I am missing, s I am not able to replicate the conditional variance for either of the ones listed above:**

I have chosen $X$ to be $v_t$ but I don't understand why in the variance above it is $P_t$ pluss $sigma^{2}$

$E\left(X^{2}\right)-E(X)^{2}=variance(X)$

$X=\left(Y_{t}-a_{t}\right)$,

where $Y_{t}=\alpha_{t}+\varepsilon_{t}$

$E\left(X^{2}\right)=E\left(Y_{t}^{2}-2 Y a_{t}+a_{t}^{2}\right)$

$E\left(\alpha^{2}+2 \alpha_{t} \varepsilon_{t}+ \varepsilon_{t}^{2}-2\left(\alpha+\varepsilon_{t}\right) a_{t}+a_{t}^{2}\right)-E\left(\alpha_{t} +\varepsilon_{t}\right.$$\left.a_{t}\right)$

Distributing E through
$
Since error being identically distributed:

$\left(\varepsilon_{t}\right\}^{2}=\left(\varepsilon_{1-1}\right)^{2}=\left(sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}\right)$

Comment: $\mathrm{Var}(\alpha_{t}+\varepsilon_{t}-a_{t}|Y_{t-1})=\mathrm{Var}(\alpha_{t}+\varepsilon_{t}|Y_{t-1})=\mathrm{Var}(\alpha_{t}|Y_{t-1})+\mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_{t}|Y_{t-1})+2\mathrm{Cov}(\alpha_{t},\varepsilon_{t}|Y_{t-1})=P_{t}+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}$.

Comment: @Q9y5 could you specify why -alpha drops out. I suspect it’s because of condition of Y_(t-1) and also would it be possible to see why the formula is as you have described.

Comment: For the first equal sign, given $Y_{t-1}$, $-a_{t}$ is known, hence it won't affect variance. The second equal sign is direct expanding of variance. The last equal sign I use an additional assumption that I guess should be implied in your textbook that $\epsilon_{i}$ is independent of $\alpha_{t}$ and $Y_{t-1}$.